I need to move from sqlite to a distributed setup. What are my options?
I have an sqlite db that has grown to 30gb and I'm still pushing data to it everyday. I have a couple services that write to it using libsqlite3. Soon it will become too big to keep locally. What is the best way for me to migrate to a distributed setup? One way I can think of is sshfs but that won't work if my machine is offline. A solution that caches the most recently used parts of my db locally and keeps the rest somewhere else would be perfect. Most of the time I'll be using recently pushed data. I could start archiving years old data but accessing it will require manual work.

"Soon it will become too big to keep locally.' - I'm assuming this implies your application is mobile device bound. If so, you can continue to use SQLite as your local database system and only store the necessary recent data, as you mentioned, while utilizing some other (probably) RDBMS that's server based to persist all of the data. There's plenty of mainstream ones to choose from, it just depends on other factors such as cost, familiarity, user base, if any specific features matter to you, etc.

I was hoping there was a single solution designed to handle this situation since it looks like a very common use case. i.e. A small local cache which caches transactions as well, combined with a large off device store.

There is not a single database system that runs both localized and on a server for the same instance with automatic synchronization management, that I'm aware of. If there were, it would be pretty niche and probably be more work to figure out how to use than sticking to the standards like SQLite locally and a mainstream server based RDBMS. There are some tools to help facilitate managing synchronization between the two, but even those are a little niche and not something I've found worth implementing.

@J.D. There is a SQL Anywhere (started as Watcom, then Sybase, currently belong SAP). It is designed to be an embedded and server RDBMS at the same time. Same database file, two executable engines (dbeng and dbsrv). Plus, builtin ETL. Very nice from technical point of view, but extremely poor marketing.

@WhiteOwl Perhaps its Wiki is equally poor at marketing it, as it doesn't mention anywhere that SQL Anywhere "runs both localized and on a server for the same instance with automatic synchronization management". Would be interested if you had a source that mentioned otherwise though.

@J.D. Yes, that is correct. SA is one of the least know, but extremely powerful RDBMS. With SA, I can take a database file, copy it as is to several remote machines (either in embedded or server mode) and setup one- or two-way ETL on builtin "SQL Remote". The ETL mechanism does exist in the engine from the box. Or you can setup automatic mirroring of db to a secondary machine with automatic switch of users if primary machine dies. Or did I not understand your wish correctly?

@WhiteOwl That's closer to what I was saying. But are you able to enable SQL Remote between a localized copy (such as on a mobile device) and a server copy of the database file? If so, how does it handle things such as offline mode when the mobile device is not currently available?

@J.D. Yes offline work is a standard for SQL Remote - it is a message based protocol. It extracts all changes since last extract, packs it into one file and it is sent to remote storage via ftp/samba/email/whatever. The receiving agents monitors inbound folder and unpack-load changes. If some gap detected - it puts a request for resend, which would be satisfied in the next communication session. All this is in the box, just some setup required. If you want online ETL (and can ensure connection between two servers), then you can use Mobilink - another "from the box" solution of SA.

@WhiteOwl Yes, I'm familiar with 3rd party synchronization systems. But IMO at that point it's more work than just using a standard localized system like SQLite and a standard mainstream remote one (e.g. SQL Server). But if SQL Remote handles both offline and online synchronization (in near realtime) between a localized and remote database instance of SQL Anywhere, as an out of box feature of it, then that's uniquely interesting.

If I understand you environment correctly, then the best way would be to do a "timestamp based" partitioning.
Keep current business objects in the operational copy of the database, move historic business objects to an archive database. Setup a one-way ETL from current db to the archive one.
Start with copying your whole DB to a desktop with a lot of storage space.
Then you have two competing ways, choose whatever looks easier:

Create a secondary DB with the same table structure. Attach it to your big database (https://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html), copy current business objects to it.
Make a copy of big database, delete from it historic business objects, Do vacuum (https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).

Now you have an archive and work database. Copy the work database to your work platform. And think about ETL.
There is a nice ETL for sqlite as extension: https://sqlite.org/sessionintro.html It would allow you to easily create batches with all new changes in the work database to be repeated in the archive one. But downside - you will need to update the client application to enable and use the extension.
Another way is to make a separate application. It would scan the work database for expired business objects, extract them into some transport file (json usually), delete these objects from the work database and vacuum it. Then you would have to move transport files to the archival side and load them into archival database. Not an easy solution, but reliable, easy understood by clients, and can be implemented even if you by some reason unable to modify client application.
